# Unity seems to be stuck rendering through camera outside of play mode

Tags: unity, c#

This may or may not be a dumb question, as I am very new to Unity, but for some reason Unity is rendering through a camera after exiting play mode.

[image: Image of my editor]

I had this issue with another project originally, so I created a new project to see if it was an error with my scripts or  animations. However, even in a blank project with nothing but a square within the camera's FOV, I still can't edit my scene.

The same issue occurs with pause mode, as well. When I am playing my game, and want to test an adjustment, it just freezes my scripts and camera playback.

Help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in the Game tab. Look at the top of the game view where you see the tabs "Scene", "Game", and "Asset Store". Click the Scene tab to go back to the scene view.

[image: Scene and Game tabs in screenshot]

You can drag these tabs apart so each one has a separate place in your editor UI, so that one never hides the other.